# Magento 2 after x days of order place , need to send new email to the customers

Tags: magento2, orders, cron, customer-emails

Magento 2 - How can I send new mail to customer, if any order has been placed  by banktransfer and more that 7 days since order placed.

I need to send mail using Crons.

This is my code:

```
<?php

namespace Arnavcancleorder\Cancleorder\Cron;

use Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroup;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;


class Sendemail extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    private $orderRepository;

    /**
     * @var SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    private $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    private $filterBuilder;
    private $filterGroup;
    private $orderManagement;

    protected $_request;
    protected $_transportBuilder;
    protected $_storeManager;


    public function __construct(
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
        FilterGroup $filterGroup,
        OrderManagementInterface $orderManagement,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
        , \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
        , \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
        , \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->orderRepository       = $orderRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->filterBuilder         = $filterBuilder;
        $this->filterGroup           = $filterGroup;
        $this->orderManagement       = $orderManagement;
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }


    public function execute()
    {
        $today          = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
        $to             = strtotime('-2 min', strtotime($today));
        $to             = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $to);

        $filterGroupDate      = $this->filterGroup;
        $filterGroupStatus    = clone($filterGroupDate);
        $filterGroupEmail      = clone($this->filterGroup);


        $filterDate      = $this->filterBuilder
            ->setField('updated_at')
            ->setConditionType('to')
            ->setValue($to)
            ->create();
        $filterStatus    = $this->filterBuilder
            ->setField('status')
            ->setConditionType('eq')
            ->setValue('ced_credit_limit')
            ->create();

            $filterEmail  = $this->filterBuilder
                    ->setField('email_msg')
                    ->setConditionType('eq')
                    ->setValue('2')
                    ->create();

            $filterGroupDate->setFilters([$filterDate]);
            $filterGroupStatus->setFilters([$filterStatus]);
            $filterGroupEmail->setFilters([$filterEmail]);


            $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->setFilterGroups(
                [$filterGroupDate, $filterGroupStatus,$filterGroupEmail]


        );
        $searchResults  = $this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria->create());



        foreach ($searchResults->getItems() as $order) {
           $names=$order->getCustomerEmail();

          $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('40')
            ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $store])
            ->setTemplateVars(
                [
                    'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore(),
                ]
            )
            ->setFrom('general')
            // you can config general email address in Store -> Configuration -> General -> Store Email Addresses
            ->addTo($names)
            ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
        return $this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What email you want to send? Magento order email or any other custom email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a module with name STech_Order and create the files like below steps:

**Step 1:**
Create **registration.php** under:

> app/code/STech/Order/registration.php

with below content:

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'STech_Order',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step 2:**
Create **module.xml** under:

> app/code/STech/Order/etc/module.xml

with below content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="STech_Order" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Step 3:**
Create **crontab.xml** under:

> app/code/STech/Order/etc/crontab.xml

with below content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="order_mail" instance="STech\Order\Cron\Run" method="execute">
            <schedule>*/1 * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

**Step 4:**
Create **Run.php** under:

> app/code/STech/Order/Cron/Run.php

with below content:

```
<?php
namespace STech\Order\Cron;

class Run 
{
    protected $_logger;
    protected $_orderCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory
    ){
        $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        foreach($this->getOrders() as $order){
            echo $order->getIncrementId();
            // Do your email code
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function getOrders()
    {
        $pMethod = 'banktransfer';
        $to = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
        $from = strtotime('-7 day', strtotime($to));
        $from = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $from);

        $collection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$from, 'to'=>$to));
        $collection->getSelect()->join(["sop" => "sales_order_payment"], 'main_table.entity_id = sop.parent_id', array('method'))->where('sop.method = ?',$pMethod);
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Change cron settings according to your requirement.

Run setup upgrade, di compile and other required commands and test.

Comment: Thanks a lot for comment MR.Sukumar Gorai , i have one small doubt ,actually  i want to send an email (from email template) to customers based on  who all are crossed 7 days from order placed time & date .

Comment: you can try this https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-create-custom-email-templates/

Comment: If you dont mine please check my code once , in this iam checking 3 condition if it satifies  email shoud go once only , but here its going to only one customer and may times

Comment: You need to create one table for your custom module and add the order ids when email is sent for flag so that email will not send next. You need to check the flag before sending email.

Comment: ok, what i did is i created extra column in sales order , after email has sent to customer ia trying to instert some value in that column using object manager direct update query   in side execute() funtion but it not inserting , any idea  please i was trying a lot for this please help me on this thanks

Comment: Load that order and try to set value and save the order object should work. Don't create column in the database directly. Use installschema in your module.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82897/discussion-between-chala-chalapathi-and-sukumar-gorai).